# Best way to replace multiple chars in string

Tags: python, regex, replace

I want to replace certain characters in a string like below:

Input string:

```py
s = "1kgbutter2kilochilli30gmssalt"
```

Output string:

```py
s = " 1kg butter 2kilo chilli 30gms salt"
```

I have tried using `re.sub` like below but no luck.

```py
re.sub(r"^[0-9]*(kg|kilo|gm)s$", "*how do i add spaces if exp matches*", s)
```

Comment: What if there is only 1 `gm`? Then, `s` might be a part of the next word.

Comment: it will be 1gms only.. 's' won't be part of next word.

Comment: Then use `re.sub(r'\d+(?:kg|kilo|gm)s?', r' \g<0> ', text).strip()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```py
re.sub(r'\d+(?:kg|kilo|gm)s?', r' \g<0> ', s)
```

NOTE: If you need to avoid the resulting spaces at the start or end of string, add `.strip()` at the end of the `re.sub`.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/UGP3yr/2). Details:

- `\d+` - one or more digits
- `(?:kg|kilo|gm)` - `kg`, `kilo` or `gm`
- `s?` - an optional `s` char.

The `\g<0>` is a backreference that inserts the whole match back into the resulting string.

See [this Python demo](https://ideone.com/btNdUm):

```py
import re
s = "1kgbutter2kilochilli30gmssalt"
print( re.sub(r'\d+(?:kg|kilo|gm)s?', r' \g<0> ', s).strip() )
# => 1kg butter 2kilo chilli 30gms salt
```

Comment: Thank u. This is what I am looking for. I am new to python.. not aware of so many things yet.